# how to extract rows from a json file in php

Tags: php, json

I am using php to look through a json file and write the contents to a table. The json file has a link and a title, and I would like to have those in separate columns.

I tried $row['link'] but it only returns a single character. How do I get it to display the value?

Thanks.

```
echo '<table style="width:100%">';
echo ' <tr><td>Link</td><td>Title</td></tr>';
foreach ($json as $value) {
    foreach($value as $row){
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo $row;
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row;
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Example JSON:

```
[{"link": ["/sof/5431137499.html"], "title": ["Nikon D800"]},
{"link": ["/sof/5431130932.html"], "title": ["14mm Lens"]},
{"link": ["/sof/5430958337.html"], "title": ["Camera Bag"]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
echo '<table style="width:100%">';
echo '<tr><td>Link</td><td>Title</td></tr>';
foreach ($json as $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo $value['link'][0];
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo $value['title'][0];
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: When I gave that a try, it displayed 
Link Title
{ -- only the first charachter

Comment: thanks, I change the way I was reading out the json and it works. seems like I was chasing the wrong dragon, again....

Comment: Glad that you found your problems. Dragons are the worst! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` to turn it into an array and then loop through it. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and the playground [here](https://eval.in/514394).